# IllegalStateException during deployment: Operator IN on type requires a Collection argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to create this Spring Data Repository:

***API Endpoint using [specification-arg-resolver](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver):***

```
@GetMapping("find")
    public Page<CustomersFullDTO> getAllBySpecification(
            @And({
                    @Spec(path = "status", spec = In.class),
            }) Specification<Users> specification,
            Pageable pageable
    ) {
        return customersService.getAllBySpecification(specification, pageable)
                .map(g -> CustomersFullDTO.builder()
                        .id(g.getId())
                        ......
                        .build()
                );
    }
```

***Interface:***

```
public interface CustomersService {
    Page<Users> findAll(int page, int size);

    Page<Users> getAllBySpecification(final Specification<Users> specification, final Pageable pageable);
}
```

***Service:***

```
@Override
public Page<Users> findAll(int page, int size) {
    return dao.findAllByTypeIn(PageRequest.of(page, size), "CustomerUser");
}

@Override
public Page<Users> getAllBySpecification(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable) {
    return this.dao.findAllByTypeIn(specification, pageable, List.of("CustomerUser"));
}
```

***Repository:***

```
@Repository
public interface CustomersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Users> {

    Page<Users> findAllByTypeIn(Pageable page, String... types);

    Page<Users> findAllByTypeIn(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable, List<String> types);
}
```

When I deploy the package I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Operator IN on type requires a Collection argument, found interface org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification in method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page org.engine.plugin.production.service.CustomersRepository.findAllByTypeIn(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,java.util.List).
```

Do you know how this issue can be fixed?

Comment: Specification & derived will not work together, put in clause also in specification

Comment: Can you show me how to modify the code please?

Comment: Why you are using specification it's not clear? Did you write anything with specifications which is passed in repo method?

Comment: Yes, when I sue it this way  `Page<Users> findAllByTypeIn(Specification<Users> specification, Pageable pageable);` it's working

Comment: Why you are not using something like _@Spec(path = "types", spec = In.class)_ ?

Comment: I want at lower level to use a "marker" to get rows which contain only value "CustomerUser". Search values should not have any impact into this.